# NSScrollView and kCAGravityResizeAspectFill

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, calayer, nsscrollview

How can I scroll a layer inside `NSScrollView`? Which contains an image and it's `ContentsGravity` is `kCAGravityResizeAspectFill`. I mean how to scroll the offscreen layer inside `NSScrollView`? I can't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (after searching a week and asking) there is no way, I solve it by keep the layer ContentsGravity kCAGravityResizeAspect and resize the NSView frame